# Highcharts, Can you change the chart type for drilldowns?

Tags: types, charts, highcharts, drilldown

Highcharts, Can you change the chart type for drilldowns?

I would like to present a standard "column" chart initially and then drilldown to a "bar" chart, I have tried everything I could think of....

I assumed it would be set in the drilldown code, but doesnt seem to work this way.
As in...

```
drilldown: {
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Chart1',
    categories ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28'],
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    color: colors[0]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what have you tried, but you can do it.
Take a look my [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7Ss6/).

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{
                    y: 55.11,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 21.63,
                    color: colors[1],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Firefox versions',
                        categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 11.94,
                    color: colors[2],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Chrome versions',
                        categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                            'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                        data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                        color: colors[2]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 7.15,
                    color: colors[3],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Safari versions',
                        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                        color: colors[3]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 2.14,
                    color: colors[4],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Opera versions',
                        categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                        data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                        color: colors[4]
                    }
                }];

        function setChart(options) {
            chart.series[0].remove(false);
            chart.addSeries({
                type: options.type,
                name: options.name,
                data: options.data,
                color: options.color || 'white'
            }, false);
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(options.categories, false);
            chart.redraw();
        }

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                var options;
                                if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                    options = {
                                        'name': drilldown.name,
                                        'categories': drilldown.categories,
                                        'data': drilldown.data,
                                        'color': drilldown.color,
                                        'type': 'pie'
                                    };
                                } else { // restore
                                    options = {
                                        'name': name,
                                        'categories': categories,
                                        'data': data,
                                        'type': 'column'
                                    };
                                }
                                setChart(options);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: colors[0],
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.y +'%';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var point = this.point,
                        s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                    if (point.drilldown) {
                        s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                    } else {
                        s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: name,
                data: data,
                color: 'white'
            }],
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Make sure you don't have a `type` defined for all your series. [Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.type)

Comment: @CityCollegeSouthampton Pete ?

Comment: Thanks for that example. If I change the first chart to 'bar' instead of 'column', i am getting an error when I switch to the drilldown pie: "TypeError: series.yAxis is undefined"

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an error in the example, the categories in the drilldown chart are undefined. Tried to fix it but can't figure it out.

Comment: Is it possible to have the drilled-down chart be displayed in another div? Can we set 'renderTo' property and make it work? Have tried in many ways but it always drills-down in-place. Could anyone please assist?

Comment: @Sayuri I think it's not possible, maybe you should handle click events and create a new chart on it's callback.

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann: Hi! Actually i did it. Just modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/452/, to include another div element in the html; and added chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
               renderTo: 'container2',
               
           }

in the setChart() and commented out chart.series[0].remove();

Comment: Has anyone had any luck getting the Categories to show properly for the drilldown? It doesn't seem fixed in this nor in any of the examples presented in this comment chain.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think it's enought if you define each serie's type

```
$(function () {
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        type: 'column',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: //your drill data
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: //your drill data
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: //your drill data
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: //your drill data
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: //your drill data
        }]
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffc4jhb7/

Best regards

Comment: I tried bar to line and bar to pie with this code, and it works. Oddly enough, you can't go from bar to column which I'm trying to accomplish right now.

Answer (score 0):

check this:

Documentation

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series

Original example

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

try this example:

```
$(function () {
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                [
                    'v40.0',
                    5
                ],
                [
                    'v41.0',
                    4.32
                ],
                [
                    'v42.0',
                    3.68
                ],
                [
                    'v39.0',
                    2.96
                ],
                [
                    'v36.0',
                    2.53
                ],
                [
                    'v43.0',
                    1.45
                ],
                [
                    'v31.0',
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    'v35.0',
                    0.85
                ],
                [
                    'v38.0',
                    0.6
                ],
                [
                    'v32.0',
                    0.55
                ],
                [
                    'v37.0',
                    0.38
                ],
                [
                    'v33.0',
                    0.19
                ],
                [
                    'v34.0',
                    0.14
                ],
                [
                    'v30.0',
                    0.14
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v36',
                    2.32
                ],
                [
                    'v37',
                    2.31
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v31',
                    0.33
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    2.56
                ],
                [
                    'v7.1',
                    0.77
                ],
                [
                    'v5.1',
                    0.42
                ],
                [
                    'v5.0',
                    0.3
                ],
                [
                    'v6.1',
                    0.29
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.26
                ],
                [
                    'v6.2',
                    0.17
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                [
                    'v12.x',
                    0.34
                ],
                [
                    'v28',
                    0.24
                ],
                [
                    'v27',
                    0.17
                ],
                [
                    'v29',
                    0.16
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

});