# Highcharts - Can a column chart drill down to a bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a project where the data in the main chart is best represented as a column chart and the data in a drilldown should be a bar chart.

However when I try to drilldown, the drilldown is still a column chart even with the type set to bar.

Is this possible to do with the provided Highcharts drilldown API?  I would like to have the "back" button and support multiple drilldown levels.

Here is a basic example that demonstrates the problem:

```
$(function () {    

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
})
});
```

Here is a JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/N2g98/

**EDIT:  This seems like it could be considered a bug in Highcharts as it is more of a problem than just drilling down from a column to a bar chart.  If you start with a bar graph and drill down to a line graph, the axes are messed up in the drilldown.**

**EDIT2: Here is the solution I ended up with**

```
 $(function () {

 (function (H) {

     H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'init', function (proceed, series, options, x) {
         var point = proceed.call(this, series, options, x),
             chart = series.chart,
             tick = series.xAxis && series.xAxis.ticks[x],
             tickLabel = tick && tick.label;

         if (point.drilldown) {

             if (tickLabel) {
                 if (!tickLabel._basicStyle) {
                     tickLabel._basicStyle = tickLabel.element.getAttribute('style');
                 }
                 tickLabel.addClass('highcharts-drilldown-axis-label').css({
                     'text-decoration': 'none',
                         'font-weight': 'normal',
                         'cursor': 'auto'
                 }).on('click', function () {
                     if (point.doDrilldown) {
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             }
         }


         return point;
     });

     H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'setDOMEvents', function (proceed) {
         proceed.call(this);
         var pointer = this,
             container = pointer.chart.container;
         container.onclick = function (e) {
             if (typeof pointer.onContainerClick === 'function') {
                 pointer.onContainerClick(e);
             }
         };
     });

     H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'drillUp', function (proceed) {
         if (!this.customDrilldown) {
             proceed.call(this);
         } else {
             var userOptions = this.userOptions;
             var drilldownLevels = this.drilldownLevels;
             var level = drilldownLevels.pop();
             var newChartConfig = level.userOptions;

             this.destroy();
             $(userOptions.chart.renderTo).highcharts(newChartConfig);
             var newChart = $(userOptions.chart.renderTo).highcharts();
             newChart.drilldownLevels = drilldownLevels;
             if (drilldownLevels.length !== 0) {
                 newChart.showDrillUpButton();
             }
             newChart.customDrilldown = true;

             HighchartsAdapter.fireEvent(newChart, 'drillup', {
                 seriesOptions: newChartConfig
             });
         }

     });



     H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'doDrilldown', function (proceed, _holdRedraw) {

         if (!$.isPlainObject(this.drilldown)) {
             proceed.call(this, _holdRedraw);
         } else {
             var newChartConfig = this.drilldown;
             var oldChart = this.series.chart;
             var userOptions = oldChart.userOptions;
             var drilldownLevels = oldChart.drilldownLevels;
             if (!drilldownLevels) {
                 drilldownLevels = [];
             }

             var oldSeries = this.series;
             var level = {
                 userOptions: userOptions,
                 seriesOptions: oldSeries.userOptions
             };


             drilldownLevels.push(level);

             oldChart.destroy();
             $(userOptions.chart.renderTo).highcharts(newChartConfig);
             var newChart = $(userOptions.chart.renderTo).highcharts();
             newChart.drilldownLevels = drilldownLevels;
             newChart.showDrillUpButton();
             newChart.customDrilldown = true;

             HighchartsAdapter.fireEvent(newChart, 'drilldown', {
                 point: this,
                 seriesOptions: newChartConfig
             });

         }

     });
 }(Highcharts));


 var pieDD1 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 5
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 25
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD2 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 15
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 25
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD3 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 3
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 5
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD4 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 50
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 3
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD5 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 13
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 11
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD6 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 50
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 25
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD7 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 5
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 5
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD8 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 15
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 5
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD9 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 4
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 8
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD10 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 33
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 66
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD11 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 9
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 1
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD12 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 8
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 13
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD13 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 70
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 25
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD14 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 50
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 10
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD15 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 8
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 5
         }]
     }]

 };

      var pieDD16 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'colors'
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Color',
         data: [{
             name: 'Red',
             y: 5
         }, {
             name: 'Blue',
             y: 8
         }]
     }]

 };



 var drilldown = {
     chart: {
         type: 'column'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'subtitle'
     },
     xAxis: {
         type: 'category',
         title: {
             text: 'X Axis'
         }
     },
     yAxis: {
         title: {
             text: 'Y Axis'
         }
     },
     plotOptions: {
         column: {
             stacking: 'normal'
         }
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Widget A',
         data: [{
             name: 'Qtr 1',
             y: 5,
             drilldown: pieDD1
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 2',
             y: 25,
             drilldown: pieDD2
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 3',
             y: 25,
             drilldown: pieDD3
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 4',
             y: 20,
             drilldown: pieDD4
         }]
     }, {
         name: 'Widget B',
         data: [{
             name: 'Qtr 1',
             y: 25,
             drilldown: pieDD5
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 2',
             y: 5,
             drilldown: pieDD6
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 3',
             y: 5,
             drilldown: pieDD7
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 4',
             y: 15,
             drilldown: pieDD8
         }]
     }]


 };

 var drilldown2 = {
     chart: {
         type: 'column'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     subtitle: {
         text: 'subtitle2'
     },
     xAxis: {
         type: 'category',
         title: {
             text: 'X Axis'
         }
     },
     yAxis: {
         title: {
             text: 'Y Axis'
         }
     },
     plotOptions: {
         column: {
             stacking: 'normal'
         }
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Widget A',
         data: [{
             name: 'Qtr 1',
             y: 15,
             drilldown: pieDD9
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 2',
             y: 15,
             drilldown: pieDD10
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 3',
             y: 30,
             drilldown: pieDD11
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 4',
             y: 5,
             drilldown: pieDD12
         }]
     }, {
         name: 'Widget B',
         data: [{
             name: 'Qtr 1',
             y: 5,
             drilldown: pieDD13
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 2',
             y: 25,
             drilldown: pieDD14
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 3',
             y: 10,
             drilldown: pieDD15
         }, {
             name: 'Qtr 4',
             y: 20,
             drilldown: pieDD16
         }]
     }]


 };

 // Create the chart
 $('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
         type: 'bar'
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Basic drilldown'
     },
     xAxis: {
         type: 'category'
     },
     plotOptions: {
         column: {
             stacking: 'normal'
         }
     },
     series: [{
         name: 'Yearly Orders',
         data: [{
             name: 'Location 1',
             y: 100,
             drilldown: drilldown
         }, {
             name: 'Location 2',
             y: 150,
             drilldown: drilldown2
         }]
     }]
 });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skTHx/22/

Comment: Might want to [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13295988/2732991).

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would use the Highcharts provided drilldown functionality so as to allow for the use of the "drill up" button and multiple levels of drilldown.  Note that setting the type on the drilldown series works for other types (pie, line), just not bar.

Comment: Weird. It seems to notice as well (you can see the animation is different from 'column' to 'bar'), but doesn't rotate it.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to destroy chart and create you one, because series update, doest allow to invert chart dynamically.