# Highcharts - Stack Chart to Stack Chart in Drilldown

Tags: charts, highcharts, drilldown

Hope someone can help, I've search examples of this but can't get them to work on my particular setup.  I have a stacked column chart in Highcharts representing 5 sets of data for each day of the week.

[image]

I then select a day to see an hourly breakdown of the day, I have the data coming through but I can't get the 5 values I have for each hour to stack on top of each other. (in the same way as the first chart) - ideally this second chart would be an area chart)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: 'Reset'
    }
});

// Create the chart
$('#chart2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        height: 300
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
       text: null
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Select a day to expand to hourly data'
    },

    legend: {
            enabled: false
        },


    tooltip: {
         formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point,
                s = 'Day: <b>' + point.name + '</b><br/>Utilisation: <b>' + this.y + '% </b><br/>';
            if (point.drilldown) {
                s = 'Day: <b>' + point.name + '</b><br/>Utilisation: <b>' + this.y + '% </b><br/>Select to view hours';
            } else {
                s = 'Time: <b>' + point.name + '</b><br/>Utilisation: <b>' + this.y + '% </b><br/>Reset to return';
            }
            return s;
            }

        },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        //categories: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        //categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
    },

    yAxis: {
         title: false, // {text: 'Utilisation'},  Y axis title - taken text out
         tickPositions: [0, 50, 70, 100],   // Y axis labels
         labels: {
            format: '{value}%'      // Y axis labels with % suffix
        },
        min: 0,                     // Following lines setting the grids to off adding min max
        max: 100,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        alternateGridColor: null,
        plotBands: [{ // Below Avg.
            from: 0,
            to: 50,
            color: 'rgba(255,108,96, 0.5)',
            label: {
                // text: 'Below Average',
                style: {
                    color: 'rgba(153,194,98, 0.8)'
                }
            }
        }, { // Average
            from: 50,
            to: 70,
            color: 'rgba(248,211,71, 0.5)',
            label: {
                // text: 'Average',
                style: {
                    color: 'rgba(153,194,98, 0.8)'
                }
            }
        }, { // Above Avg.
            from: 70,
            to: 100,
            color: 'rgba(153,194,98, 0.5)',
            label: {
                text: 'Above Average',
                style: {
                    color: 'rgba(153,194,98, 0.8)'
                }
            }
        }]
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Status 5',
        color: '#86C9F2',       
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: true,
        data: [<?php echo $data7a5?>]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Status 4',
        color: '#6FB2DB',
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: true,
        data: [<?php echo $data7a4?>]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Status 3',
        color: '#589BC4',
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: true,
        data: [<?php echo $data7a3?>]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Status 2',
        color: '#4184AD',
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: true,
        data: [<?php echo $data7a2?>]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'At the Desk',
        color: '#2B6E97',           //rgb(43, 110, 151)
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: true,
        data: [<?php echo $data7a?>]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        drillUpButton: {
            //relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
            position: {
                y: 10,
                x: -10
            },
        theme: {
                fill: 'white',
                stroke: 'silver',
                r: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#41739D',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            id: 'D2',
            data: [['8', 13.77],['8', 2.74],['8', 1.27],['8', 2.64],['8', 2.28],['9', 29.30],['9', 6.44],['9', 3.79],['9', 5.11],['9', 5.32],['10', 36.41],['10', 9.01],['10', 5.47],['10', 7.11],['10', 7.06],['11', 34.12],['11', 7.50],['11', 4.48],['11', 10.02],['11', 8.28],['12', 26.82],['12', 5.03],['12', 5.79],['12', 15.00],['12', 10.27],['13', 30.08],['13', 5.40],['13', 5.34],['13', 11.73],['13', 9.57],['14', 33.90],['14', 7.75],['14', 4.78],['14', 6.41],['14', 9.33],['15', 33.27],['15', 7.73],['15', 4.95],['15', 8.11],['15', 7.09],['16', 31.29],['16', 8.53],['16', 4.51],['16', 6.44],['16', 5.81],['17', 17.36],['17', 3.87],['17', 2.06],['17', 4.47],['17', 3.42],['18', 4.79],['18', .38],['18', .79],['18', 1.44],['18', 2.45]]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            id: 'D3',
            data: [<?php echo $data7b2?>]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            id: 'D4',
            data: [<?php echo $data7b3?>]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            id: 'D5',
            data: [<?php echo $data7b4?>]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            id: 'D6',
            data: [<?php echo $data7b5?>]
        }]
      }
    });
```

});

I've shown the first drilldown data so you can see the structure.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Can you put it in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: And you are using **php**, so use the tag.

Comment: Hi Raeen, I've added the code to JSFiddle but havng not used it before I can't get it going.  Here is the link though http://jsfiddle.net/robdwright/uxo2edzu/5/

Comment: You're JSFiddle wasn't running. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/uxo2edzu/6/

Comment: I don't think it is possible using the default drilldown functionality, but you might want to look at some workarounds, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293629/highcharts-can-you-change-the-chart-type-for-drilldowns

Comment: Thanks Ondkloss - yeah I've not used JSFiddle much so thanks for getting it working - appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the type of drill-down data from `['time', data]` to `[time, data]`:

```
data: [
                ['8', 13.77],
                ['8', 2.74],
                ['8', 1.27],
                ['8', 2.64],
                ['8', 2.28],
                ['9', 29.30],
                ['9', 6.44],
                ['9', 3.79],
                ['9', 5.11],
                ['9', 5.32],
                ...
]
```

to:

```
data: [
                [8, 13.77],
                [8, 2.74],
                [8, 1.27],
                [8, 2.64],
                [8, 2.28],
                [9, 29.30],
                [9, 6.44],
                [9, 3.79],
                [9, 5.11],
                [9, 5.32],
                ...
]
```

And I also changed the `tooltip.formatter` to show the correct tooltip for drill-downs. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxo2edzu/7/)

Comment: Raeen, that is excellent - I can't believe it was the single quotes around the time!!  Thank you for the update to the tooltip as well.

Comment: Hi Raeen, hoping you can assist with this last piece.  I've been trying to modify the demo and add the colors for the drill down stack to be the same as the initial stack columns.  I've added a set of colors to the Highcharts.setOptions  code e.g. colors: ['#2B6E97','#4184AD','#589BC4','#6FB2DB','#86C9F2'] and also something similar to the drilldown series but no joy!

Comment: I think I've figured it out using a settin gin plotOptions and colorByPoint and then setting the colors as the comment above - drilldown colors now work - messed up the initial stack but I will get there!

Comment: Well, it turns out I didn't need colorByPoint but instead and plotOptions for column and then area.  Still can't get the drilldown area to fill and it only shows the markers and the tooltip only shows the top result in the drilldown.  Any help would be appreciated.  http://jsfiddle.net/robdwright/uxo2edzu/53/

Comment: These following problems should be asked as another question dude, but your data is nothing near area. Area has one marker in each column not 5.

Comment: Okay I will add it as another question - apologies.